# web2py: <body>-Tag Attributes

Tags: web2py

I need to specify an attribute for the body-tag as follows:

```
<body onresize="window.location.href=window.location.href">
```

Of course I can do this in the corresponding view. But then I have two opening body-tags in the resulting HTML code. The HTML code works, but is not compliant to given standards.

Thus, my question is, if there is a way to specify the attribute, that it is included in the generated response body-tag.

Thanks for any support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "layout.html" view, you can do something like this:

```
<body{{=XML(' onresize="window.location.href=window.location.href"') if response.resizable_body else ''}}>
```

Then in a model or controller, you can do:

```
response.resizable_body = True
```

Or in a view (note, the `resizable_body` attribute is set *before* extending the layout):

```
{{response.resizable_body = True}}
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

There is no need to explicitly set `response.resizable_body` to `False` at any point, as `response.resizable_body` will simply be `None` by default (`response` is a `Storage` object, so when you attempt to access a non-existent attribute, it simply yields `None`).

Comment: Perfect and quite more elegant than having different layout views.

Thanks Anthony!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found the solution ... it's all easy when you think ;-)

Since the body-tag derives from extending "layout.html" {{extend 'layout.html'}} one can change the body-tag there. If there is the need not to have the onresize attribute for all views, one can have an adaption of "layout.html" for example "layout-onresize.html" for this special purpose.

Comment: Note, if the attribute needs to be conditional, it is simpler to use a solution like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513969/440323) rather than create an entirely separate layout view.